# Retrieving a record with breeze

Tags: breeze

I develop an application with asp.net mvc + breeze.

So far, I retrieve a specific record (based on id) like this:

```
var getTransportById = function (transportId, transportObservable) {
       return manager.fetchEntityByKey('Transport', transportId, true)
               .then(fetchSucceeded)
               .fail(queryFailed);
}

function fetchSucceeded(data) {
   var s = data.entity;
   return ...
}
```

Now I need to retrieve the same record but need to 'expand' the property named *sender* which links to another entity (table). I did not find a way to 'expand' one property through **fetchEntityByKey** so I used a query like this:

```
var getTransportById = function (transportId, transportObservable) {
    var query = EntityQuery.from('Transports')
                           .where('id', 'eq', transportId)
                           .expand('Sender')
                           .orderBy(orderBy.transport);

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(fetchSucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);
}

function fetchSucceeded(data) {
    var s = data.results[0];
    return ...
}
```

**My question:** is it the good way to proceed? Is there another way of doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a query from an EntityKey and then expand whichever properties you want.  Something like this:

```
var entityKey = new EntityKey("Transport", transportId);
// expand whichever nav props you want here. 
var query = EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey).expand("Sender").orderBy(...);
return entityManager.executeQuery(query).then( {
  ...
});
```

Comment: I don't know why but when I try your code, it works only for already existing elements in cache. It does not work when I previously add a new entity to the local cache like this: `var newTransport = manager.createEntity(entityNames.transport, initialValues); manager.addEntity(newTransport);` Note that it worked with my original code.  Any idea?

Comment: I don't know what your model looks like, but are you sure that the entity you've just added links via either it's primary or foreign key to the 'sender' that you are expecting.

Comment: Jay: one question: `EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey)` is it searching in the local cache or on the server? The use of `manager.fetchEntityByKey('Transport', transportId, true)` allows me to search in the local cache thanks to the third parameter set to `true`. I need to search in the local cache because this is a newly added entity.

Comment: EntityQuery.fromEntityKey returns an EntityQuery.  Any EntityQuery by default is a remote query but you can make it a local query via a 'using' clause and a FetchStrategy, i.e. query.using(FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache)